# How to get "to_do" from a notion block using typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, notion-api

Recently I tried final version of Notion API. Using typescript I made a retrieve block children request:

```
(async () => {
    const blockId = process.env.BLOCK_ID;
    const response = await notion.blocks.children.list({
        block_id: blockId,
        page_size: 50,
    });
    console.log(response.results[1].to_do);
})();
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T0qc.png)

For some reason typescript tells me that `to_do` doesn't exist in type `(PartialBlockObjectResponse | BlockObjectResponse)`. I looked at type definition and... it was there:

```
declare type BlockObjectResponse = {
    // ...
    {
    type: "to_do";
    to_do: {
        rich_text: Array<RichTextItemResponse>;
        color: ApiColor;
        checked: boolean;
    };
    object: "block";
    id: string;
    created_time: string;
    created_by: {
        id: IdRequest;
        object: "user";
    };
    last_edited_time: string;
    last_edited_by: {
        id: IdRequest;
        object: "user";
    };
    has_children: boolean;
    archived: boolean;
} 
// ...
}
```

I tried making type guard

```
function isToDo(value: PartialBlockObjectResponse | BlockObjectResponse): value is BlockObjectResponse {
     return "to_do" in value;
}  /* Error: TS2304: Cannot find name 'PartialBlockObjectResponse'. */
```

and importing type from package

```
import type {PartialBlockObjectResponse} from "@notionhq/client/build/src/api-endpoints"; 
// Error: Module '"@notionhq/client/build/src/api-endpoints"' declares 'PartialBlockObjectResponse' locally, but it is not exported.
```

Neither helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Frustratingly) That package [does not export its types](https://unpkg.com/browse/@notionhq/client@1.0.3/build/src/api-endpoints.d.ts). There's an open [issue](https://github.com/makenotion/notion-sdk-js/issues/219) about it in the repo.

But you can work around this using a generic with your predicate function:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwMIBtgFMB2MC+cBmUEIcA5AAKYQzASYAWAjgPQDGaWMpA3AFAAm6dgEMo6OKzoBneFRp0AXHFQZsfQSLETp8AEYoIrANYBJfkplRgmAOZ9e+AK6ZW8zHGBSAKhH4Q4ADxecOgAHjBY-FJwAEpC0PwBltY2ADRwzkZUAO6YAHx5ABQQugBWSl4AlEolpR7RwQBkiHAwAJ5g6EqkMBAA+n6kcHgIvHBwYjCOUO49HehD1nC1cI3NtQB07Z1wALz7ZL0DEDy8OLy8hcJSbS5whZV7eYhj2pgyE+hSkO-iu3DCbLCYCyai0TAbfSGIxSDasejAFD8MQQtAyQoIKHGPrAcxwLGmfjpMDCGzoPpSYAALy6cAArAAGHCVezjfDQe6Sd7wMRSRwoeAQfCfb7SdAbXn8mBSR6jcbjYDCwqeHx+QqSgWVWWveUiqVbfp+bhwZgAKh1ustcAAerbbRaFdEcq0EdFtl0HS8rbqrPC+hFwkoYsB4V4wjATBEQHFRb8ANoAXT43vlkgMUCUAEEwMAkBB08mUxJ6EIjOg8boIPn0MJMIXdecrabmBbG8MzpUHrwgA)

```ts
import {Client} from '@notionhq/client';
declare const notion: Client;
declare const blockId: string;

function isTodo <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(obj: T): obj is T & { type: 'to_do' } {
  return 'type' in obj && obj.type === 'to_do';
}

(async () => {
  const response = await notion.blocks.children.list({block_id: blockId, page_size: 50});

  for (const result of response.results) {
    if (isTodo(result)) {
      result.to_do; /*
             ^^^^^
      is now this type:
      {
          rich_text: RichTextItemResponse[];
          color: ApiColor;
          checked: boolean;
      }
      */
    }
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer assumes that you cloned [this notion-sdk-typescript-starter](https://github.com/makenotion/notion-sdk-typescript-starter) repo.
The way I solved this issue was to go to the api-endpoints.d.ts file and replace PartialBlockObjectResponse (inside the ListBlockChildrenResponse type) with a new type that matches the desired response structure you are looking for. Here is what that looks like:

```
export declare type ListBlockChildrenResponse = {
    type: "block";
    block: EmptyObject;
    object: "list";
    next_cursor: string | null;
    has_more: boolean;
    results: Array<DesiredBlockObjectResponse | BlockObjectResponse>;
//                  ^^^ here is where PartialBlockObjectResponse is deleted 
//                     and replaced
```

The new type that I implemented looks like this:

```
export declare type DesiredBlockObjectResponse = {
    type: "block";
    block: {
        type:string,               
        object: string,
        id: string,
        parent: { type: string, page_id: string },
        // ... more info if desired
    }
    object: "block"
    
};
```

I hope this helps!